# single tableview cell in navigation

Tags: iphone, navigation, uitableview

hello everyone i need solution for one small query.follow the below link
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html
in this link you can see download sample code button..this sample code is base on the sqlite database
but i want to implement the instuction section same as this application but with the plist file use..
so anybody can help? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should use `NSDictionary` `initWithContentsOfFile:`